# node and express error "cannot GET /" even after I included app.get() in my server.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to start my project via launching server.js but I am getting error:"cannot GET /"
even after I made an app.get() route in my server.js

I am using also "body-parser" as a middleware, and "cors"

server.js:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
const projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();
/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('views'));
const port = 8080;
app.use(express.static('dist'));


// Setup Server
const server=app.listen(port, ()=>{console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`)});
app.get('/all', sendData);

function sendData (request, response) {
  response.send(projectData);
};

// TODO-ROUTES!
app.post('/add', Info);

function Info(req, res) {
  projectData['date'] = req.body.date;
  projectData['temp'] = req.body.temp;
  projectData['content'] = req.body.content;
  res.send(projectData);
}
module.exports = server;
```

Comment: So what URL are you trying to hit? `localhost:8080/all` ?

Comment: when I visit localhost:8080/all I get empty {}  as result

Comment: Is because you have an empty object. You have to first call POST /all to fill you object, and then call GET /all to get you object.

Comment: well, what can I do so it doesn't become empty?

Comment: You have to first call POST /all to fill you object, and then call GET /all to get you object.

Comment: @OscarLópez please tell me more, currently I am trying to make my project start via the server.js file so I can't make post request before project launches, do you get me?

Comment: @OscarLópez so it means client side code which has the post request won't launch until server.js launches correctly

Comment: No, the server is ok. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a POST request to /add and it works. Then I call GET /all and also work. The error cannot GET / is because you are requesting an endpoint that not exists.
[image]

[image]

Comment: you think I should just add client-side post request?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a dummy data to your Fn() if you want to see some output on GET request wihtout making any post request
Here is my solution

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/all');
})
```

we need this because you do not have any root URL set, so we set the root URL to redirect to `/all`

2nd step then we add a dummy data in the `projectData`

```
var projectData = {
date = new Date().getDate();,
temp = 10,
content="This is Test Content"
}
```

This way when you call 'http://localhost:8080/' you shall get redirected to `http://localhost:8080/all` and instead of empty `{}` you shall see the dummy data.

Comment: dummy data are giving me this error "SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer"

Comment: yes you will need to formate the JS obj as per your codeing style.. iin my case i use '=' you might have used ':'

Comment: yes I fixed them but now the error is Cannot GET /all after being redirected

Comment: app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/all');
}) This needs to go at the end of the all routes and maybe before the fn().. You cannot GET because you must have copied the above code on top on the router stack.. and hence its getting called always

Comment: redirection happens successfully, this means the issue is not in the syntax of it

Comment: Then maybe try commenting the above code of root url redirection and see.. oh and one mroe thing add the status code to the re-direct res.redirect(200,'/all');